# Merging sorted lists

Tags: c, sorting

I have four sorted lists and I want to merge them into one sorted list.
What is the most efficient way to do that? If the implementation can be done in parallel, it's a plus.

Comment: How big are those lists typically?

Comment: I want to do it in C, not python.

Comment: Ohh, sorry, sorry, I don't know why I thought about python

Comment: There was a `python` tag on this question when it first appeared and it was removed during the editing grace period.

Comment: Where should the result go, can it be a new list (or a sequential write to a file) or must it be done *in-place* ?

Answer (score 4):

This is the merge part of [merge sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort).

Just take the minimum of the four elements at the head of each list and dump it into the output one.  Repeat until all lists are empty.  Assuming that `min4` is a fixed cost, then this is just going to be O(N).

If you have more information (such as the range of the list) you can probably improve things a little, but I don't think these affect the asymptotic complexity.

Comment: Parallelizing merges isn't as simple as I thought it would be => As I delete my answer, I find it meaningful to +1 this.

Comment: This section of the wiki page, and the references it makes are pertinent: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Merge_sort#Parallel_processing